# How to save object in to files using visual studio cordova

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing hybrid mobile app using visual studio cordova, angular js and ionic framework. I want to save some objects into a file system.

Are there any specific or common file location that can be access via visual studio cordova to store data. I'm trying to get a platform specific local storage( not html 5 localStorage) place to save data.

any supporting articles or API pls? couldn't find a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

No there's not a common file location or something like that. This basically leaves you with two options. Either you use a database such as WebSQL, IndexedDb or a native database such as SQLite. Or you use the Cordova file plugin which should provide an abstraction layer for the file system.

Please take a look at the [Cordova File plugin repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) or the [Cordova Async IndexedDb plugin repo](https://github.com/ABB-Austin/cordova-plugin-indexeddb-async).

Comment: i'm following https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file .Can you please give me an sample code snippet to follow?

Comment: I wonder if [this documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) is compatible with the newer versions of Cordova.